# How to setup Reverse Proxy on NGINX to External Website (with a path)

Tags: nginx

suppose i Have a server on ip 111.111.111.111
on which nginx server is installed as a web server

I want that if someone visit on 
http://111.111.111.111/new

They should see the content of 
http://example.github.io/new

Someone told me it is possible via NGINX Reverse Proxy or Apache Reverse Proxy

The trick of configuring **sites-enabled/default** works fine for locally hosted sites on different port but it is not working for external website.

What i have done for this (on server 111.111.111.111):
in **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /new/ {
                proxy_pass http://example.github.io/new;
                proxy_redirect          default;
                proxy_buffering         off;
                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol    $scheme;
        }
}
```

What i got :
404

There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

Comment: Your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` does not match your question. Are you suggesting that the URI `/iiitd-rs-16/` should reverse proxy `http://ashutoshanand.com/iiitd-rs-16/` but is returning 404 instead?

Comment: @RichardSmith Sir i have corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages allows repository owners to associate a domain with that repository, which it verifies by making sure that domain's A/CNAME records are pointed to GitHub.

If you are pointing the entirety of your domain to this GitHub page, then you do not need a reverse proxy, as the A records will accurately point your domain to GitHub Pages.

Your configuration aims to only reverse proxy a directory of your domain, instead of your domain as a whole. However, you are setting your Host header to match the Host header as requested by the client. As a result, GitHub Pages is checking if that repository is configured to receive traffic as 111.111.111.111, which it is not. This is why you receive the 404 error -- there is not a GitHub Pages configuration that matches that repository and host combination.

Change the Host header in proxy_set_header to example.github.io so that, even though the client requested 111.111.111.111, GitHub receives the request as a request for example.github.io.